# Any good way to set the exit status of a Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsapplication

I have a Cocoa app which interacts with a server and displays a GUI. If there is a fatal error, I display an alert and exit. I'd like to set the exit status to a non-zero value to reflect that an error occurred, for ease of interaction with some other UNIX based tools.

Unfortunately I've been unable to find a good way to do so - NSApplication doesn't seem to have any way to set an exit status. At the moment, I've subclassed NSApplication and added an `exitStatus` ivar (which I set in my app delegate when necessary), then overridden `-terminate:` so that it calls `exit(exitStatus)`. This works fine, but it seems a bit grungy to me, not to mention that I may be missing something important that the standard `terminate:` is doing behind the scenes. I can't call `[super terminate:sender]` in my subclassed method, because that `exit()`s without giving me a chance to set the status.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Just call exit(3) -- there really isn't even a reason to call anything else. The OS will clean up everything as necessary. The only reason you might want to wait is if /you/ are doing anything special, like closing up sockets nicely, disconnecting users, cleaning up your own temp files, destroying semaphores, etc. But then you can do all that in an atexit hook anyway...

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'd still like my delegate to get `-applicationShouldExit:` and friends, hence my subclassing. But it's good to know that whatever happens in the standard `-terminate:` isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you either call `exit(3)` and completely bypass the standard Cocoa tear down mechanisms *or* you don't get to set the exit code (without jumping through the hoops as you describe.

As Jason mentioned, there isn't anything critical *to the system* that happens during app tear-down.  Your app, on the other hand, may have something critical, but that is entirely because of your app's implementation (and not anything in Cocoa, by default).

But, really, don't do that -- user's love to force quit out of spite and your app should be engineered to not fail catastrophically as a result of that.

Answer (score 1):

There are other cleaner methods for interacting with unix based tools. For example, you could simulate the exit code by writing some code in a text file, from where the tools could pick it up, without hacking your app to return a code. It could also be possible to use the app's stdout/console.